# Замена элементов в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив с числами Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 11 [2] => 11 [3] => 11 [4] => 24 [5] => 23 [6] => 24 [7] => 24 [8] => 23 [9] => 24 ...
) 
Нужно заменить '24' => '10', '11' => '6', '23' => '1' результат суммировать и вывести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на учебное задание или собес. =/

```
$arr = array ( 0 => 11, 1 => 11, 2 => 11, 3 => 11, 4 => 24, 5 => 23, 6 => 24, 7 => 24, 8 => 23, 9 => 24);
$replaces = array(24=>10,11=>6,23=>1);

foreach($arr as &$value){
  if(isset($replaces[$value])){
    $value = $replaces[$value];
  }
}
print(array_sum($arr));
```

Comment: Собеседование на джун-джун-джуниора?

Comment: Нет, 1 сентября же уже наступило. Если вы понимаете, о чем я.

Comment: Это второгодник ;)